# Flipping the output of a depth shader

Tags: shader, depth

**SOLVED!!** Eureka! Oh man... It's 5 days I struggle upon this problem, as soon I ask for help i fix it! O_o
I had to invert the texture inside the Fragment Shader ONCE before the lookup (tex2dproj) and ONCE after that and before the Linear01Depth.
Like that:

```
//Fragment Shader
half4 frag (v2f i) : COLOR{
           i.scrPos.y = 1 - i.scrPos.y;
           fixed4 preRender = tex2Dproj(_PreTex, i.scrPos);
           i.scrPos.y = 1 - i.scrPos.y;
           float depthValue = Linear01Depth (tex2Dproj(_CameraDepthTexture, UNITY_PROJ_COORD(i.scrPos)).r);
 etc........
```

---

I'm using Unity, I have an ortho camera with a renderTexture do get the depth of the scene from botton to top using a vertex/fragment shader.

I know there are different behaviours between DirectX and OpenGL about how the y-axis is rendered and that the simple turnaround is flipping it in vertex. Here's my basic shader.

```
Shader "Custom/DepthGrayscale" {

SubShader {
    Tags { "RenderType"="Transparent" }

    Pass{           
        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag
        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        sampler2D _CameraDepthTexture;

        struct v2f {
           float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
           float4 scrPos : TEXCOORD0;              
        };

        //Vertex Shader
        v2f vert (appdata_base v){
           v2f o;
           o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos (v.vertex);
           o.scrPos = ComputeScreenPos(o.pos);
           o.scrPos.y = 1 - o.scrPos.y; //here's where the magic happens!
           return o;
        }

        //Fragment Shader
        half4 frag (v2f i) : COLOR{
           float depthValue = Linear01Depth (tex2Dproj(_CameraDepthTexture, UNITY_PROJ_COORD(i.scrPos)).r);
           fixed4 depth;

           depth.r = depthValue;
           depth.g = depthValue;
           depth.b = depthValue;
           depth.a = depthValue;

           return depth;
        }
    ENDCG
    }
}
FallBack "Diffuse" }
```

Now, I want to get the "trails" of the objects when they move. To achieve this I use a similar shader with a texture property, that is another renderTexture on which I save the output of the render and, at the same time, is used to blend the current frame with. Here's the DepthTrace Shader.

```
Shader "Custom/DepthTrace" {

Properties {
    _PreTex ("", 2D) = "white" {}
}

SubShader {
    Tags { "RenderType"="Transparent" }

    Pass{
        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag
        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        sampler2D _CameraDepthTexture;

        struct v2f {
           float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
           float4 scrPos : TEXCOORD0;
        };

        //Vertex Shader
        v2f vert (appdata_base v){
           v2f o;
           o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos (v.vertex);
           o.scrPos = ComputeScreenPos(o.pos);
           o.scrPos.y = 1 - o.scrPos.y;
           return o;
        }

        sampler2D _PreTex;

        //Fragment Shader
        half4 frag (v2f i) : COLOR{
           fixed4 preRender = tex2Dproj(_PreTex, i.scrPos);
           float depthValue = Linear01Depth (tex2Dproj(_CameraDepthTexture, UNITY_PROJ_COORD(i.scrPos)).r);
           fixed4 depth;

           if (preRender.r < depthValue) {
                depthValue = preRender.r;
           }

           depth.r = depthValue;
           depth.g = depthValue;
           depth.b = depthValue;
           depth.a = depthValue;

           return depth;
        }
    ENDCG
    }
}
FallBack "Diffuse" }
```

Now, the "trail" effects works good but I get a
[double specular image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7MEl.png).

If I don't flip the y-axis, I get a [good image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyKWG.png), of course entirely flipped on his y-axis.

It almost seems that the depth input is flipped whereas the _PreTex is not!

I won't simply flip the output in a regular script, I'd lost every advantage of the GPU calculations in terms of performance.

Do you have any idea why this happens? Thank you.